# MySQL query for joining many tables when the row matches one of a list of userIDs

Tags: mysql

How would we go about this?

Also I have to go through 30+ tables of sharded user information that are named in this fashion userinfo_1, userinfo_2, userinfo_3... etc.

Anyone know of an effective query for this scenario?

Comment: That sounds horrible. Can you change the table design?

Comment: Nope. Corporate spaghetti trap. Can't and won't bother :P

Comment: There's no magic bullet, you just have to write a bunch of `JOIN` clauses. You could automate it with dynamic SQL that gets all the table names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if there's one individual software developer moving from company to company implementing these bad designs, and then leaving, so others have to maintain them forever.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the data your table(s) have and an example of the output you want would help a lot.